# Returning two values to main method without arrays

Tags: java

- Create a program named rockPaperScissors.java
- The program should validate user input.
- Game should ask the user to play again and continue if yes and stop if no.
- Once the user stops playing, program should print the total number of wins for the computer and
  for the user.

I am trying to learn programming from a book, so I am not good at this. I need to return the values of Cwin and Uwin to the main method, but I know how to return one value to it. I also have a problem with looping the question. I cannot use arrays and could only use the basic while loops (without the (true) and break).

```
import java.util.*;
public class rockPaperScissors
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Play again? Type yes or no.");
        String YoN= input.next();
        if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                game();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "/nUser wins: " + Uwin);
            }
        }
    public static void game()
    {
        System.out.println("Choose rock, paper, or scissors. Type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors.");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        int choice = console.nextInt();
        int Uwin = 0;//user win count
        int Cwin = 0;//computer win count
        int result = -1;
        if (choice > 1 || choice < 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type 1, 2, or 3."); 
        }
        int comp = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
        if (comp == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer chose rock.");
        }
        if (comp == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer chose paper.");
        }
        if (comp == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer chose scissors.");
        }
        if (choice == 1 && result == 2)
        {
            Cwin++;
        }
        if (choice == 2 && result == 3)
        {
            Cwin++;
        }
        if (choice == 3 && result == 1)
        {
            Cwin++;
        }
        if (choice == 2 && result == 1)
        {
            Uwin++;
        }
        if (choice == 3 && result == 2)
        {
            Uwin++;
        }
        if (choice == 1 && result == 3)
        {
            Uwin++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of returning, you can have global variables at the top of your class, above your main function. ```int UWin = 0; int CWin = 0; ``` this way it can be used in both main() and game()

Comment: Dont recomend static

Comment: You need to return an object that holds two values inside of it

Comment: Either arrays or some kind of new class. Java's record syntax is great for this, if your compiler is new enough to support it

Comment: also use a ```while()``` loop to keep the game going. replace the ```if``` with ```while(YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) { game(); System.out.println("Play again? :"); String YoN= input.next(); ``` then you can remove the else and just have the print statement, as it will execute once the player enters no

Comment: Why you don't learn it? It's not a big headache. Anyways just concatenate 2 values into a single string and return it and split it.

Comment: `return (((long) Uwin) << 32) | Cwin;` `</irony>` --- A remark on the code: in Java, class names should be written in `CamelCase` (`rockPaperScissors` -> `RockPaperScissors`), while variables should be written in `camelCase` (`Uwin` -> `uWin`, `Cwin` -> `cWin`).

Comment: @Turing85 I love your solution! However, I fear that if the OP is having trouble with arrays, bitwise operators are unlikely to make any more sense :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return multiple values from a method you may use an array that stores the values in its elements. Check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/returning-multiple-values-in-java/).

However for this program there is no need for returning 2 values(and you also said "I cannot use arrays"). Instead you can have 2 global variables that record the number of times the player wins and the number of times the computer wins respectively. Lets call them `playerWinCount` and `computerWinCount`.

Now that we got that down, lets look at how we allow the user to replay the game. You say that can use only "basic while loops". Fine. What we do is we declare a variable `choice` that holds the user's entry when prompted to replay. We initialise `choice` to `true` and then keep asking the user if he'd like to play again until he decides not to.

```
        String choice = "yes" ;

        while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            playGame() ;

            System.out.print("Play again(Yes/No)? ") ;
            choice = scanner.next() ;
        }
```

The `playGame()` method has the code to play the game.

The way we validate the user's entry is by using a length check. If the entry is out of range(i.e. from 1 to 3 inclusive)  he'll be prompted to enter again.

```
        boolean valid = false ;
        while(valid == false)           // loop will run until a valid number is entered
        {
            System.out.print("Choose rock, paper, or scissors. Type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors: ") ;
            playerPick = scanner.nextInt() ;

            // validation of the user's entry
            if(playerPick < 1 || playerPick > 3)  
                System.out.println("Invalid entry! Try again.") ;
            else
                valid = true ;            
        }
```

Having acquired a valid user input, the next thing we do is get a random number as the computer's pick(you've done that). Then we check who won the game and increment the number of times the winner has won. We can do this using a number of `if` statements like this:

```
        // first we check if the computer and player did not pick the same thing
        if(playerPick != computerPick)
        {
            if(playerPick == 1 && computerPick == 3)        // check if the player picked rock(1) and the computer picked scissors(3)
            {
                playerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Player won!") ;
            }
            else if(playerPick == 3 && computerPick == 2)   // check if the player picked scissors(3) and the computer picked paper(2)
            {
                playerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Player won!");
            }
            else if(playerPick == 2 && computerPick == 1)   // check if the player picked paper(2) and the computer picked rock(1)
            {
                playerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Player won!");
            }
            else                                            // otherwise, the computer has won this round
            {
                computerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Computer won!") ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        }
```

Or we can just combine the 3 conditions of winning with the OR operator(`||`) and use just 2 `if` statements:

```
        if(playerPick != computerPick)
        {
            if((playerPick == 1 && computerPick == 3) || (playerPick == 3 && computerPick == 2) || (playerPick == 2 && computerPick == 1))
            {
                playerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Player won!") ;
            }
            else
            {
                computerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Computer won!");
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        }
```

And that's about it.

Here's the entire code:

```
import java.util.*  ;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    static int playerWinCount, computerWinCount ;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        playerWinCount = 0 ;
        computerWinCount = 0 ;
        String choice = "yes" ;

        while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            playGame() ;

            System.out.print("Play again(Yes/No)? ") ;
            choice = scanner.next() ;
        }

        System.out.println("\nNumber of times you won: " + playerWinCount) ;
        System.out.println("Number of times computer won: " + computerWinCount) ;
        System.out.println("Goodbye!") ;
    }


    public static void playGame()
    {
        System.out.println("") ;
        
        Random random = new Random() ;
        int playerPick = -1 ;
        int computerPick = -1 ;
        boolean valid = false ;

        while(valid == false)           // loop will run until a valid number is entered
        {
            System.out.print("Choose rock, paper, or scissors. Type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors: ") ;
            playerPick = scanner.nextInt() ;

            // validation of the user's entry
            if(playerPick < 1 || playerPick > 3)  
                System.out.println("Invalid entry! Try again.") ;
            else
                valid = true ;            
        }

        computerPick = random.nextInt(3) + 1 ;
        System.out.println("The computer picked " + computerPick) ;

        
        // first we check if the computer and player did not pick the same thing
        if(playerPick != computerPick)
        {
            if(playerPick == 1 && computerPick == 3)        // check if the player picked rock(1) and the computer picked scissors(3)
            {
                playerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Player won!") ;
            }
            else if(playerPick == 3 && computerPick == 2)   // check if the player picked scissors(3) and the computer picked paper(2)
            {
                playerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Player won!");
            }
            else if(playerPick == 2 && computerPick == 1)   // check if the player picked paper(2) and the computer picked rock(1)
            {
                playerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Player won!");
            }
            else                                            // otherwise, the computer has won this round
            {
                computerWinCount++ ;
                System.out.println("Computer won!") ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go point by point.

You aren't taking the user input for determining the choice of playing in a while loop, so your game won't run more than once. You can take that input as:

```
while (true) {
     System.out.println("Play again? Type yes or no.");
     String YoN= input.nextLine();
     if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
         game():
     } else {
         System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "/nUser wins: " + Uwin);
         break;
     }
 }
```

If user gives input other than `yes`, you're trying to print `Cwin` and `Uwin`, but you haven't declared those variables in the scope of main method. So your program won't compile anyways.
You can keep global variables in the class running main method.

```
 public static int Cwin = 0;
 public static int Uwin = 0;
```

**Update**

I've gone through your code and found a few more problems. As far as I understand, you want to receive choice input from user and validate it in this segment:

```
if (choice > 1 || choice < 3) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type 1, 2, or 3.");
}
```

Well, this condition doesn't supports what you've printed inside, this `choice > 1 || choice < 3` condition always gets `true`. Also, you haven't prompted to take the entry from the user again.
You can fix this issue as below:

```
while (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type 1, 2, or 3.");
    choice = console.nextInt();
}
```

Then you're trying to make random choices for Computer. But you're selecting through upper bound and adding `1` to it. Why not set the bound to `1` more?

```
int comp = r.nextInt(4);
```

Then, finally, you're trying to compare the `choice` and the `result`. Where result was assigned `-1` at the time of declaration and was never changed. That's why it'll never enter any if blocks and the `Cwin` and `Uwin` will always print `0`. I bet you wanted `comp` here, in place of `result`. Also, I've tried to make the program more understandable to user while running.

```
    if (choice == 1 && comp == 2) {
        Cwin++;
        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
        return;
    }
    if (choice == 2 && comp == 3) {
        Cwin++;
        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
        return;
    }
    if (choice == 3 && comp == 1) {
        Cwin++;
        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
        return;
    }
    if (choice == 2 && comp == 1) {
        Uwin++;
        System.out.println("You win!");
        return;
    }
    if (choice == 3 && comp == 2) {
        Uwin++;
        System.out.println("You win!");
        return;
    }
    if (choice == 1 && comp == 3) {
        Uwin++;
        System.out.println("You win!");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("It's a draw!");
```

It will work as expected if you fix the aforementioned issues.

**Note:** I haven't refactored your code, I've just pointed out the problems and fixed it without modifying it much. It can be made lot more better than the current condition. Let's keep the topic for another day's question.

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code somewhat.
You mention in a comment that you don't want to use an array and static variable.
so, I tried some different method hope It will help you.
**It is fully working code**

```
import java.util.*;
public class rockPaperScissors {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome To Rock Paper scissors Game Type yes to continue or no for close.");
    String YoN = input.nextLine();
    if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        game();
    } else if(YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Thank You");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Enter valid input");
    }

}

public static void game() {
    int Uwin = 0;//user win count
    int Cwin = 0;//computer win count
    int tie = 0;//Tie count
    while (true) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Are you sure!!! Want to continue? Type yes or no.");
        String YoN = input.nextLine();
        if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Choose rock, paper, or scissors. Type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors.");
            int choice = console.nextInt();
            int result = (int) (Math.random()*(3-1)) + 1;
            if (choice < 1 || choice > 3) {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please type 1, 2, or 3.");
            }
            if((choice == 1 && result == 3) || (choice == 2 && result == 1) || (choice == 3 && result == 2)) {
                System.out.println("Computer Choose"+result);
                Uwin++;
            }else if((choice == 1 && result == 2) || (choice == 2 && result == 3) || (choice == 3 && result == 1)) {
                System.out.println("Computer Choose"+result
                        );
                Cwin++;
            }else {
                System.out.println("Computer Choose"+result);
                tie++;
            }
        } else if(YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "\nUser wins: " + Uwin+"\nTie: "+tie);
            System.out.println("Thank you");
            break;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Enter valid input");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

## Track the score separately from the individual game

It looks you've written your `game()` method to play a single game of Rock, Paper, Scissors. In that case, you only need to return one value: who won that single game. Then your main method can keep track of the current scores and print out the totals after it's all done.

Consider an approach like the following:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class rockPaperScissors {

    public final static int USER_WON = 1;                // Added these constants
    public final static int COMPUTER_WON = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Uwin = 0;// user win count                   // Moved from `game()`
        int Cwin = 0;// computer win count               // Moved from `game()`
        System.out.println("Play again? Type yes or no.");
        String YoN = input.next();
        if (YoN.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            int winner = game();                         // Modified this line 
            if (winner == USER_WON) {                    // Added this section
                Uwin++;
            } else {
                Cwin++;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Computer wins: " + Cwin + "/nUser wins: " + Uwin);
        }
    }

    public static int game() {                           // Modified this line
        System.out.println("Choose rock, paper, or scissors. Type 1 for rock, 2 for paper, and 3 for scissors.");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        //// Truncating for brevity ////
        if (choice == 3 && result == 1) {
            return COMPUTER_WON;                         // Modified this line
        }
        if (choice == 2 && result == 1) {
            return USER_WON;                             // Modified this line
        }
        //// Truncating for brevity ////
    }
}
```

Notice that I moved the `Uwin` and `Cwin` variables out of `game()` and into your `main` method. Then I changed `game()` to return an integer instead of nothing (`void`) and replaced the `Cwin++` and `Uwin++` statements with a simple `return COMPUTER_WON` or `return USER_WON` based on the results of the rock, paper, scissors match. That return value can then be processed in your `main` method to keep a running total of how many games each player has won.

## Use a `class`

If you're interested in trying something more advanced, consider creating an Object to encapsulate the two values you want to return.

For example, by storing both win counts in a simple Scoreboard object like the one below would enable you to return the two win counts at the same time and encapsulate the process of printing the scoreboard to the screen.

If you go this route, you'd have to make sure that all games reference the same Scoreboard. There are a variety of ways to do this from using a class variable, to passing the Scoreboard as a function parameter to the `game()` method, to moving all your logic for playing multiple games into the `game()` method. There are lots of options for you to try out and see which works best for you in this situation.

```java
public class Scoreboard {
    
    private int computerWins;
    private int playerWins;

    public Scoreboard() {
        computerWins = 0;
        playerWins = 0;
    }

    public void addComputerWin() {
        computerWins++;
    }
    public void addPlayerWin() {
        playerWins++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Scoreboard: "
            + "\n - Computer wins: " + computerWins 
            + "\n - Player wins: " + playerWins;
    }
}
```